# How can I know if the scroll event was raised using the mouse wheel, or manipulation of the cursor on the scrollbar?

Tags: javascript

I am currently catching with an event when the `scrollbar` is moved.

I need to know how the `scrollbar` was changed, if it was caused by the `mouse wheel`, or if it was caused by clicking directly on the `scrollbar` and moving it.

I know a `mousewheel event` exists but I want to know if I can do what I need within my current `listener`.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll",(scroll)=>{
 console.log(scroll)
})
```

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

*{
 box-sizing:border-box !important;
}

#final{
  border:1px solid red;
}

.height500vh{
 height:500vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="height500vh"></div>
<div id="final">final</div>
```

Comment: You can't, the event does not contain this kind of information. Besides, scrolling can be caused by different factors: mouse, touch, scrollbar, arrows, spacebar, page up, page down, etc.

Comment: You would likely need detect multiple types of events, then detect if any of those events coincide with a scrolling event.